# How to fill database sqlite tablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am writing "SQLite" database and I create the database table like this:

```
void MainWindow::createdata()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("DROP TABLE messages");
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE messages("
               "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
               "IPAddress VARCHAR(20),"
               "date VARCHAR(10),"
               "message VARCHAR(30))");

    query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message) values(?,?,?)");
    query.addBindValue("192.168.1.1");
    query.addBindValue("jun 3 2016");
    query.addBindValue("hello");

    if (query.exec()) {
        qDebug() << "ok!";
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << query.executedQuery();
      qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }
 }
```

And i create "qtablewidget" like this:

```
 QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();

 table->setRowCount(10);
 table->setColumnCount(4);
 table->setWindowTitle("Received Message");
 table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
  table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("ID;HostAddress;Date;Message").split(";"));
 table->setStyleSheet("QTableView {selection-background-color: blue;}");
 table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
 table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
 table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);


 QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM messages");
```

but i don't know how should i fill the "tablewidget" to show with query.
Can anyone please help me?Thanks

Comment: In general the easiest way to show database data in Qt is trough a model in this case a QSqlQueryModel, here is an example: http://www.qtforum.org/article/29669/how-display-sqlite-database-table-in-qtableview.html

Comment: @ Marco: i should use tablewidget:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QTableView` (Model based version of table view) and then using  `QSqlQueryModel`, you can populate your table.

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery(query);
tableView->setModel(model);
```

---

To use `QSqlQueryModel` with a `QTableWidget`, you should iterate through `QSqlQueryModel` row by row and add them to your `QTableWidget`.

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery(query);

int i;
QSqlRecord row
for(i = 0, row = model->record(i); !row.isEmpty(); i++, row = model->record(i)){
    // Get each field using `value` method of variabale 'row'
    // and insert this fields to its corresponding cell in QTableWidget
}
```

---

Relevant Question:

[Setting the model to a QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137732/setting-the-model-to-a-qtablewidget)

Comment: @Frogatto :but i should use QTableWidget

Comment: @Hanita Why should you use `QTableWidget`?

Comment: because my boss say it :D :(

Comment: @Hanita In this case, you should iterate through `QSqlQueryModel` row by row, and add them to `QTableWidget`.

Comment: i am sorry, i am new in qt..can you explain more?